# Filter for div elements using data-* attribute only works for case sensitive search

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am trying to create a search filter for a set of cards. Each card has a *data-pname* attribute and I am using the value of this attribute for my filter.

**Problem**: The current code is unable to match "facebook" with data-name=Facebook or "messenger" with data-pname=Messenger.

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```
var addon_search = document.createElement('input');
$(addon_search).on('keyup', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('[data-pname]').hide();
    if (value.length < 1) {
        $('[data-pname]').show();
    }
    $('[data-pname*=' + value + ']').each(function() {
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `i` flag to your jQuery selector to make it case insensitive :

*PS : I also removed your last `.each()`, you don't need it.*

```
var addon_search = document.createElement('input');
$(addon_search).on('keyup', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('[data-pname]').hide();
    if (value.length < 1) {
        $('[data-pname]').show();
    }                            // v Here
    $('[data-pname*="' + value + '" i]').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank You. It looks like the i flag does not work on IE Version 11.2068.14393.0 but this worked on both Firefox and Chrome.